# What is the meaning of /*+* in robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a question regarding robots.txt file.

```
Disallow: Blog/*+*
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

In theory it would stop a robot that chose to respect it from accessing any part of the website that began with Blog/+  ; however, the bot doesn't have to respect it, and since it isn't starting with a directory indicating slash there is no telling how people's robots will deal with it.

from : http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Disallow
    The value of this field specifies a partial URL that is not to be visited. This can be a full path, or a partial path; any URL that starts with this value will not be retrieved. For example, Disallow: /help disallows both /help.html and /help/index.html, whereas Disallow: /help/ would disallow /help/index.html but allow /help.html.
   Any empty value, indicates that all URLs can be retrieved. At least one Disallow field needs to be present in a record.